# How to turn the texture in a tunnel in one direction?

Tags: unity-game-engine

We are trying to turn the texture inside a tunnel in a certain direction like this:
[image]

Simply rotating the camera is not an option since we are planning to use VR equipment.

When we used Material.mainTextureOffset (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material-mainTextureOffset.html) we got the effect that one side was turning left and the other was turning right.

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Are the two sides different objects?

Comment: @Mars No it is a tunnel-mesh that we created in sketchup and imported to unity

Comment: A video/gif would be a little more helpful, but off the top of my head, it could be anchoring of the texture or the way you were offsetting. Don't have access to unity at the moment though, so can't help much, sorry!

Comment: Most likely the problem is not with the shader, but with the meshe's UVs. You would have to pre-set them correctly in the sketchup, than apply the texture in unity.